# DevExpress WinForm TabFormControl Select Tab

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have a TabFormcontrol with 3 Tabs on a page.
I open the form by clicking on one of three buttons on my main form. 
Dependent the clicked button I want to select tab 1, 2 or 3 when opening the form.
Code in my main form:

```
Private Sub Button1_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles Button1.ItemClick
    Dim F As New frmImport ' <- the form with the 3 tabs
    F.TabFormControl1.... ' <- select Tab 1,2,3 - here comes your solution ;)
    F.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

How can I select Tab 1, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TabFormControl.SelectedPage](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.TabFormControlBase.SelectedPage.property) property. For example:

```
 F.TabFormControl1.SelectedPage = tfcPage1
```

Comment: I tried that. tfcPage1 has to be an object of type TabFormPage. Is there a way to set the number (1,2,3) of that page?

Comment: Oh, I got it: F.TabFormControl1.SelectedPage = F.TabFormControl1.Pages(2)